# Do objects need to be deleted if stored in a map of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm starting to get a grasp on pointers and avoiding memory leaks...

I have one question though... Before I begin, I am NOT using C++11 so please don't reply with information on smart pointers and such that are specific to C++11...

I have the following code...

```
class Test
{
public:
   Test(const int s_id, const std::string s_name) :
      id(s_id),
      name(s_name)
   {

   };
   const int GetID()
   {
      return id;
   }

private:
   const int id;
   const std::string name;
};

class TestCollection
{
public:
   void AddTest(Test& my_test)
   {
      tests[my_test.GetID()] = &my_test;
   }

   void RemoveTest(const int id)
   {
      if (tests.find(id) != tests.end())
      {
         tests.erase(id);
      }
   }
public:
   std::map<int, Test*> tests;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   TestCollection collection;
   Test my_test(0, "First Test");
   collection.AddTest(my_test);

   collection.RemoveTest(0);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is do I need to do anything else to clear up the memory from my_test when I call RemoveTest? So as to avoid a memory leak?

I know that when I use the new keyword I need to call delete... But what do I do in this case?

Does it just get auto cleaned up by the garbage collector?

Comment: It depends on how the objects were allocated. But better post real code.

Comment: That code won't actually compile. `tests` can only store pointers and you're trying to store a reference.

Comment: You only need to `delete` objects that you allocated with `new`. Using `delete` on other objects is undefined behavior (I think).

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've updated it so it compiles...

Comment: Ok so in your example now, you are storing a pointer to an object that's been allocated on the stack. You don't need to delete this, since it will be destroyed automatically at the end of the scope. Note that it's not the `map` that deletes it - it's just automatically destroyed when `_tmain()` returns. But this sort of pattern is of limited use; storing pointers to stack-based objects is dangerous as it can lead to use of dangling pointers and undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example both collection and my_test are allocated on the stack. As soon as the scope ends(return from _tmain) the memory will be released.

Taking pointers of stack variables that can exist outside the variable scope will result in unpredictable behavior. In this case if collection takes the object and stores the pointer rather than a copy.

Comment: What would be the alternative? To instead use pointers everywhere?

Comment: You can have the TestCollection class create a copy of the object being passed. This copy would reside in the heap and would be allocated using a new.
You would need to delete this when Remove is being called. The caller does not need to use pointers.

Comment: I am assuming the sample program that you have asked about is just a snippet. Let's say you have a large app. You will have 100's of functions / methods manipulating an object of TestCollection. When such a function calls a method on the test collection object, that would be the caller to the method. If you are storing pointers to objects allocated on the stack of  the caller, those will only be valid till the variable scope. [link] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)